# LINQ Where Clause not being triggered on

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am working with an existing database, and am creating a new API to go along side it. Part of this work is to get records from a payments table, where it has a number of related tables.

```
Payment => PaymentLines mapped by PaymentId

PaymenLines => Fund mapped by FundId

Fund => DepartmentFund mapped by FundId

Department => DepartmentFund mapped by DepartmentId
```

Because of how the original application has been written, there a department can have many fund codes and visa - versa why we have a many to many mapping table.

I have several approaches that I would take in SQL as per the small sample below (Many ways to skin a cat so to speak).

```
-- OPTION 1 - Showing the relationships
SELECT * FROM dbo.Payment p 
LEFT JOIN dbo.PaymentLine pl ON pl.PaymentID = p.PaymentID
LEFT JOIN fund f ON f.FundID = pl.FundID
LEFT JOIN DepartmentFund df ON df.FundID = f.FundID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Department d ON d.DepartmentID = df.DepartmentID
WHERE d.Code = 'BANKRECSTATEMENT'

-- Option 2
WITH cte AS (
SELECT FundId FROM dbo.DepartmentFund df
LEFT JOIN dbo.Department d ON d.DepartmentID = df.DepartmentID
WHERE d.Code = 'BANKRECSTATEMENT'
)

SELECT * FROM dbo.Payment p 
LEFT JOIN dbo.PaymentLine pl ON pl.PaymentID = p.PaymentID
WHERE pl.FundID IN (SELECT * FROM cte)
```

In the below code I have brought some code forward to help make it easier to understand and see my issue
First I get my query built, (I am using a strategy pattern to build
up the where clauses.)
Second I build the context for the strategies
Third I execute the strategies. In the code below this is where you will see which line is brought forward.
Lastly I project the results into a List of object

```
 var departmentFundQuery = _databaseContext.DepartmentFund
    .Include(department => department.Department)
    .Where(x => x.Department.Code == "BANKRECSTATEMENT");

var mappedDepartmentFund = await _mapper.ProjectTo<DepartmentFundDto>(departmentFundQuery)
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var query = _databaseContext.Payments
            .Include(paymentLine => paymentLine.PaymentLines)
            .Include(mapping => mapping.BankTransactions)
            .ThenInclude(mappedStatus => mappedStatus.MappingStatus)
            .Include(notes => notes.Notes)
            .AsQueryable();

var context = new GetBankTransactionContext
{
    Query = query,
    Request = model,
    BankAccount = bankAccount,
    FundId = mappedDepartmentFund
};


//Foreach Strategy loop ommitted 
// Strategy Query brought forward
// This where clause is the issue
 context.Query.SelectMany(x => x.PaymentLines).Where(paymentLines => context.FundId.Any(funds => paymentLines.FundID == funds.FundId));

// This fires the call with the where conditions 
var mappedTransaction = await _mapper.ProjectTo<BankTransactionDto>(context.Query)
    .ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The problem I am having is that this where clause is not being applied when I watch this through SQL Server Profiler.

What I would be expecting is an in clause with something like this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Payment p 
LEFT JOIN dbo.PaymentLine pl ON pl.PaymentID = p.PaymentID
WHERE pl.FundID IN (
68,
69,
73)
```

Any and all help on this query would very much be appreciated.

============= EDIT 1 ==============
dto

```
public class BankTransactionDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Id
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Bank Account Id
    /// </summary>
    public Guid BankAccountId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Account Number
    /// </summary>
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Sort Code
    /// </summary>
    public string SortCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Currency Id
    /// </summary>
    public CurrencyCode CurrencyCodeId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Transaction Date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Reference
    /// </summary>
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Amount
    /// </summary>
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Mapped State
    /// </summary>
    public MappedState? MappedState { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Transactions Id
    /// </summary>
    public Guid? TransactionMappingId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets flag to say has notes
    /// </summary>
    public bool HasNotes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Statement Description 1
    /// </summary>
    public string StatementDescription1 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Statement Description 3
    /// </summary>
    public string StatementDescription2 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Statement Description 3
    /// </summary>
    public string StatementDescription3 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Bank Account Name
    /// </summary>
    public string BankAccount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Ref4 (Payment Line Ref4)
    /// </summary>
    public string Ref4 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Fund Id
    /// </summary>
    public int FundId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ Expression is immutable, so you have to change property before using query for materialization:

```cs
var newQuery = context.Query
   .SelectMany(x => x.PaymentLines)
   .Where(paymentLines => context.FundId.Any(funds => paymentLines.FundID == funds.FundId));

var mappedTransaction = await _mapper.ProjectTo<BankTransactionDto>(newQuery)
    .ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: massive wood and trees moment.. thank you

Comment: When trying this I get this error 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Adelante.BankReconciliation.Data.Entities.PaymentLine]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Adelante.BankReconciliation.Data.Entities.Payment]'.'

Comment: Well, expected that ;) Let me correct answer

Comment: Note, that probably you have created wrong query for mapping to DTO.

Comment: The query may be wrong which is why I have included the SQL in the original question so show more what I am trying to do and seeing where I am going wrong.  This is a new condition that I am adding into the EF \ LINQ call to filter down the data to be more precise

Comment: I cannot help here, you have created mess of `Includes` which will be ignored after `ProjectTo`. Better to uncover DTO and your model classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240717/discussion-between-simon-price-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).